# Integral of f(|x|)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

How would you calculate the definite integral of $f(|x|)$?
In my case, $f(x)=x^2-x-2$, and when I tried to calculate the integral of $\int_{-3}^3{f(|x|)}dx$ using $2\cdot(\int_{2}^3{f(x)}dx -\int_{0}^2{f(x)}dx)$, I got the incorrect answer.
The correct way shown was $2\cdot\int_{0}^3{f(x)}dx$. I thought that this would cause a miscalculation as the negative area wasn't taken into account.
Can someone also explain why the actual answer is negative? I was under the impression that all definite integrals are positive.

Comment: I'm afraid that's just plain wrong: if you're doing a definite integral to find an area then you have to consider all of the area as positive, because you can't have negative area, but in pretty much any other case, negative parts of the graph are counted as negative in the integral. I think this makes more sense if you think of an integral as an accumulation of many small changes: when the integrand is negative, the change is negative, so the total integral decreases.

Comment: I think you are confusing f(|x|) with |f(x)|.   Whether f(x) is positive or negative is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe $f(|x|)=f(x)$ for $x>0$, so the “correct way” follows

Answer (score 1):

I'm OP answering as I have found a solution.

I was getting confused between the area under the curve (where you would have to subtract negative values of $f(x)$ in order to find the total area) and the definite integral.
In fact, the area under the curve from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is defined as $\int_{a}^b{|f(x)|}dx$ and is only positive values, as the modulus function restricts $f(x)$ to $f(x)\geq0$. I was under the assumption that $\int_{a}^b{f(x)} dx = \int_{a}^b{|f(x)|}dx$. On the other hand, the definite integral of a function simply 'tallies' the distances from $f(x)$ to the x-axis, and can take positive and negative values. Therefore, $\int_{a}^b{f(x)}dx$ CAN be negative, contrary to what I thought.
Thus, $\int_{a}^b{f(|x|)}dx$ where $a<0$ and $b>0$ is equal to $\int_{0}^{|a|}{f(x)}dx + \int_{0}^b{f(x)}dx$, and when $a=-b$, the integral is equal to $2\cdot\int_{0}^b{f(x)}dx$.

Thanks for the comments everyone.